# Excel VBA code to change pivot chart type

Tags: vba, excel, graph, dashboard, excel-2013

I'm looking for a code to create a button which upon clicking will change the pivot table chart from a bar chart to a line graph. I want the button to be at the bottom of the graph so the user can choose how they can see the data at the click of a button.

Does anyone know the code for this? Ideally a plug and play solution as I'm a beginner to VBA

Thanks

Comment: Try recording a macro then adding the resulting code to a button.

Comment: Private Sub CommandButton20_Click()
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
' Line Graph
'

'
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 60").Activate
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
    
End Sub             That's my code but I'm getting a Compile Error 'Expected End Sub' how do I fix it? Does the code look right to you? I recorded the Macro, changed the chart type and then stopped recording...

Comment: I have tidied up the code below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had two sub routines, but only one end:

```
Private Sub CommandButton20_Click()

  ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 60").Activate
  ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine

End Sub
```

Works for me.

You can also assign a macro to a chart so something like:

```
Sub ChangeMe()

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 60").Activate

    If ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine Then
            ActiveChart.ChartType = xlBarClustered
                Else
                ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
    End If

End Sub
```

might be worth investigating.

Comment: That's great! Thank you it's working well. What code do I need if I want to change the X axis of my pivot chart from App Name to Date at the click of a button? Thanks

Comment: `Charts("Chart1").SeriesCollection(1).XValues =  Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B5")` will take the values from Range `B1:B5` on `Sheet1` and use that as the x axis values of `Chart1`.

Comment: Also if the answer is working, could you tick it as accepted in case anyone else needs a similar solution? Thanks.